# What is the best way to find the proper dynamic path resource into an array of resources?

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, dynamic, path

I have the following Array of resources, including a dynamic resource ("guides/:guideId/packages") and a currentURL (guides/GUIDE007/packages):

```
const resources = ["guides", "guides/files", "guides/:guideId/packages"];
const currentURL = "guides/GUIDE007/packages";

const getResourceMatch = (resources, currentURL) => { return ... ?? }  

const resourceMatch = getResourceMatch(resources, currentURL);
console.log(resourceMatch) // guides/:guideId/packages
```

What can be the best way to find that format match into the array as the currentURL matches a resource or a resource format?

Comment: Can you give an example of maybe a function you're trying to write so we can see what you want as input and output?

Comment: A function that takes the resources array and the currentURL and then returns in this case the `guides/:guideId/packages` item because that URL matches the dynamic format

```
const resources = ["guides", "guides/files", "guides/:guideId/packages"]
const currentURL = "guides/GUIDE007/packages"

const resourceMatch = (resources, currentURL) => { return ... }
console.log(resourceMatch) `// guides/:guideId/packages`
```

Thanks @Ace

Comment: Edited to get a better code format

Comment: I provided an answer, if it answered your question please mark it as answered so others know it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I will preface this by saying you should probably try to find a library that can do route matching for you. Nevertheless, here's a route matching implementation for you that turns your resource strings into regular expressions to test the currentURL against.

```js
const resources = ["guides", "guides/files", "guides/:guideId/packages", "guides/packages/:packageId"];
const currentURL1 = "guides/GUIDE007/packages";
const currentURL2 = "guides/packages/PKG007";

const getResourceMatch = (resources, currentURL) => {
  return resources.find(r => {
    const regexStr = '^' + r.replace(/(:\w+)/g,'[\\w-]+') + '$';
    const regex = new RegExp(regexStr);
    return regex.test(currentURL);
  })
}  

const resourceMatch1 = getResourceMatch(resources, currentURL1);
const resourceMatch2 = getResourceMatch(resources, currentURL2);

console.log(resourceMatch1) // guides/:guideId/packages
console.log(resourceMatch2) // guides/packages/:packageId
```

Comment: I was wondering how should I change the regEx if I have a new dynamic path in the array, like: `guides/packages/:packageId` ??
The current regEx seems not to work for this new path...
Is there a way to add a regEx that works for a dynamic in the last /position?

Comment: @LeonardoUribe I've edited my answer to show that it should work for that path as well. Are you sure your urls look the way you expect?

Comment: Just a note: If you have a `packageId` of `packages` it will match the first path. Should there not be a `guideId` in there as well? Otherwise, you should remove `guides` from that path.